# How to reduce spacing between items in Navigation Bar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

In my Swift project I have 2 items on Right Bar but I see that spacing between them is too big. How to reduce it? Or how to move pen icon closer to time icon?[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're not in control of the spacing of separate bar button items. You could make a *single* bar button item containing a custom view holding two buttons, and then you would be in control of their spacing.